# Iframe 401 Unauthorized NGINX 3CX

Tags: nginx, iframe, cross-domain, http-status-code-401

I would like to use an `iframe` of the 3CX webclient in my website. This `iframe` works fine on Firefox and Internet Explorer but doesn't work on Chrome (the `iframe` appears but I can't login). When I go to the console on Chrome the error is:

> "Failed to load ressource: the server responded with a statuts of 401
>   (Unautorized)".

When I go in the Network tab, a **xhr** file is red, here is the capture of file header error :

[image]

I own every files of this 3CX server. As you can see 3CX use Nginx, this is the configuration file of Nginx :

```js
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  auto;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  10240;
}


http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' $http_connection;
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
 #limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:50m rate=1000r/s;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
 

    server {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        listen 5000;
        listen [::]:5000;
        server_name gesika.3cx.fr;
        server_tokens off;

        access_log off;
        error_log nul crit;

        allow 192.168.0.0/16; 
        allow 172.16.0.0/12;
        allow 10.0.0.0/8;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::0/0;
        deny all;

        client_max_body_size 300m;

        location /user_images {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location ~ /webclient/.*\.(js|css|woff|woff2|json|mp3)$ {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location ~ index\.html {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            add_header Pragma no-cache;
            expires 0;
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location / {
            index index.html;
            root C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; 
        }

        location /MyPhone {
            alias C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Http/Interface/MyPhone;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; 
        }

        location @proxy {
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5004;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

        location /management/Reports {
            alias "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Http/Reports";
        }

    }


    server {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        listen       5001 ssl;
        listen [::]:5001 ssl;
        server_name  gesika.3cx.fr;
        server_tokens off;

        access_log off;
        error_log nul crit;

        ssl_dhparam Instance1/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:60m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        ssl_certificate      Instance1/gesika.3cx.fr-crt.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  Instance1/gesika.3cx.fr-key.pem;

        ssl_ciphers  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA';

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        client_max_body_size 300m;

        location /user_images {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location ~ /webclient/.*\.(js|css|woff|woff2|json|mp3)$ {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location ~ index\.html {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            add_header Pragma no-cache;
            expires 0;
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
        }

        location / {
            index index.html;
            root "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Data/Http/wwwroot";
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location /MyPhone {
            alias "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Http/Interface/MyPhone";
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5004;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

        location /management/Reports {
            alias "C:/ProgramData/3CX/Instance1/Data/Http/Reports";
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see there is `add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";`. I have deleted this line. I also tried to replace it with this `add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM *";` but it still doesn't work. I didn't forget to reload my server.

I tried to add this in the config file :

```js
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

My iframe works on Chrome when I create a page in the same domain of the 3CX Server. So the problem is all about cross domain origin (CORS).

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

change shared header files setting in 3cx nginx conf folder 
You have few paramter like x-frame and some ancestor settings either put your website domain or remove them so that it will allow all to access.

Comment: @Tiw I have edited the answer hope it helped you little